# How can authentication details be stored json-ld compliant way?

Tags: json, mongoose, semantic-web, schema.org, json-ld

This may be a dumb question, but I am architecting a web app from scratch and looking for content to be stored in MongoDB in a JSON-LD compliant way.

My user Schema looks something like this:

```json
{"auth": {
     "local": {
        "email": String,
        "password": String,
      },
    "firebase"         : {
        "uid"          : String
    },
    "facebook": {
        "id"           : String,
        "token"        : String,
        "email"        : String,
        "name"         : String
    }
  },
 "profile_contents" : {
     "id" : {
        "firstname" : {"value": String},
        "lastname" : {"value": String},
        "email" : [String],
        "dob": Date,
        "gender": {type: String, enum: genderTypes}
     },
     "profile" : {
         "displayName": String,
         "img": String,
         "website" : String,
         "organisation": String
     }
 }}
```

Questions:

1. Most of the content in the `id` and `profile` objects will make its way to a restful endpoint. It makes sense for these to be mapped to schemas. But the `Auth` object will rarely (never?) be exposed to the API and will be used for backend operations.. should these still be mapped to a schema, if so, how?
2. Regardless of the answer to (1) are there scehmas suited to mapping credentials like those listed? (e.g. suppose we want to expose `auth.firebase.uid` at one point.. should this be part of a custom vocab or mapped to an already existing one? Schema.org didn't have anything (other than accountId - which seems to be aimed at eCommerce payment use cases).

Thanks!